# Can I restrict a vhost to only a local IP?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, virtualhost

I have a subdomain I'd like to only be accessible by a local IP address.  Is it possible to specify this in the vhost?  I'm thinking it's not since I haven't found much on Google.  If not, what's the best way to do this on an apache level?  I forget the version of Linux we're using... but we have Samba running on it.

The site I'm trying to restrict is our site's documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Default Apache VirtualHost configuration has alias for /doc/ that redirects to Apache's documentation and access is restricted only to localhost. I think that is what you are looking for. Look at the *Deny* and *Allow* lines.

```
Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can definetly disable access to a directory based on IP with mod_access (included in most linux distributions):

i.e.

```
<Directory /docroot>
 Order Deny,Allow
 Deny from all
 Allow from 10.1.2.0/24 
</Directory>
```

If you block the access to the whole document root for that vhost then the user from outside should not get more than 403 Forbidden all the time.